# How to undo window always on top?

Tags: macos, window-manager

While I'm just switching to `Terminal` window using `Cmd + Tab + Up` my `Terminal` window started floating on top of all other windows. I am unable to bring it down. I've tried `Cmd + Tab + Down` but didn't work.

Comment: That's not a standard Mac control key-combo - in fact I know of no way to permanently float a window from OS X, natively. Standard for Cmd/Tab/Up would be to bring the tabbed-to window to the front, Mission Control-style.  Esc or click would return to standard view, with that window at the front [but not locked on top]

Comment: Its a bug. I couldn't do it again with any of the windows. I couldn't reproduce the bug again even after several trials.